# Changing the first line of file and going to the last without losing data c++

Tags: c++

I'm working on a school project for C++ with involves on working with polimorfism, dynamic objects, heritage. My project consists on an main.cpp with will run a loop with options for the user to select. I will be storing some data in a file, the data will be appended so I don't loose the data that was already in the file, but my file works like the following example:

```
2
Data;12;21;0
Data2s;22;61;7
```

This is what I want to happen:

```
3
Data;12;21;0
Data2s;22;61;7
Data3s;8;2;9
```

What I'm attempting to do is, I have to change the first line to the next variable number, and I can't loose the data under it.
After I change the line, I will go to the end of the file (after numb 7) so I can add another line of data.
attempt 1:

```
void Empresa::save_data(){
    ofstream arquivoE;

    arquivoE.open("data.txt", ios::app);

    if (temp > 0){
        arquivoE.seekp(0) << num_func; 
        arquivoE.seekp(0, ios_base::end);
        arquivoE << endl;
    }else{
        arquivoE << num_func << endl;
    }

    for (int i = temp; i < num_func; i++)
    {
        arquivoE << func[i]->getNome() << ";" << func[i]->getEmissao() << ";" << func[i]->getSalario() << ";" << func[i]->last_field() << endl;
    }

    cout << " Sucesso ao gravar arquivo!" << endl;

    arquivoE.close();
    
}
```

attempt 2:

```
void Empresa::save_data(){
    ofstream arquivoE;

    arquivoE.open("data.txt", ios::out);

    arquivoE.seekp(0, ios::beg) << num_func; 
    arquivoE.seekp(0, ios::end);
    arquivoE << endl;

    for (int i = temp; i < num_func; i++)
    {
        arquivoE << func[i]->getNome() << ";" << func[i]->getEmissao() << ";" << func[i]->getSalario() << ";" << func[i]->last_field() << endl;
    }

    cout << " Sucesso ao gravar arquivo!" << endl;

    arquivoE.close();
    
}
```

num_func is the the variable from the first line, which I need to change
Temp variable is just to keep track of where to add the line
This is the data line:

```
arquivoE << func[i]->getNome() << ";" << func[i]->getEmissao() << ";" << func[i]->getSalario() << ";" << func[i]->last_field() << endl;
```

Comment: If you write a greater number of characters at the beginning of the file, you will corrupt what comes after; going from 9 to 10 lines will cause grief unless you've added dummy characters that can be overwritten.

Comment: What you mean? The first line will only contain numbers and will go from 0 to 10

Comment: When the first line goes from `9` which is one character to `10` which is two characters you're going to erase part of the second line.  Or worse, you'll overwrite the newline at the end of the first line so the two lines merge into one.    Nowhere in the question does it mention that `10` is your maximum.